# Naruto Ultimate Ninja FINAL endings?

Tags: ps2, naruto-ultimate-ninja

Okay, so I have just finished all the Scenario's for each character, and done every Practice - A-Rank Mission in Naruto Ultimate Ninja (the first one), and got to the S-Rank missions.... that's when I realized you have to be crazy to do them (if you have played the game you know what I mean; the missions are using every move or every character in the entire game, collecting 9,999,999 ryo, collect the thousands of different items from the Shop one at a time, etc.). I have an obsession with beating my games 100 PERCENT, but I am not willing to put in insane amounts of boring time to do those missions.

So my question is, what endings do you get when you beat all the S-Rank missions? And what endings do you get when you collect everything from the Shop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this question is old, but maybe someone will still care for an answer.

I assume you are talking about PS3 version. If so you don't get extra endings. You get story/ cut-scenes when you get the secret factor challenges (don't know the official name) and just beat battles. Rank doesn't change the amount of story you get.

You do get a trophy for beating all missions on S-rank, but apart from that nothing. 
In last Naruto game I bought and got everything and was pretty disappointed, because buying all the cards and titles took a while and they didn't even carry over to the next game.

**IF** however you are talking about PS2 version, then there's absolutely nothing to be unlocked by the S ranks.

Comment: I am talking about the Ps2 version. Have you completed all the S-rank missions or are you just guessing?

Comment: I've done it on Ultimate Ninja 5 (PS2) in story and any other missions I could find that register ranks. Completing a mission gets you everything, S-rank just adds extra money.

Comment: Okay. Although getting the 99,999,999 ryo mission can't earn you any money can it? Because I'm pretty sure that is the money cap.